# Sprout SEO - Characters output to decimal HTML entities

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

For some reason, "special" characters such as the apostrophe get converted to HTML entities in the `seoTitle` variable, resulting in unreadable tab titles.

[image]

As you can see, there's this `&#039;` instead of a regular `'` (what is typed into the field).

If I use `entry.title` instead, I get a clean and readable output.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to get a clean output from the `seoTitle` variable?

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify where and how the `seoTitle` variable is being created? Sprout SEO does not create that variable by default. The apostrophe seems to work fine in my initial tests so I'm wondering if this may have something to do with how `seoTitle` is being defined. Are you using the Element Metadata field to map your metadata or handling it on your own in the templates?